# Using Google Adsense, How to maintain between WebSites privacy?

Tags: javascript, adsense

I have a site that could explode in term of popularity, so I try to protect myself against non desired solicitations, just to be able to keep up with my work and things are tricky on the Google Adsense side because I have already used it on a nominal website with a Javascript having the google_ad_client ID such as xxxxxxxxxxxxxxxId and huge problem, typing this Id in Google leads immediatly to other of my sites using it, so it would not be possible to stay anonymous if a single of these site show my personnal information (it is the case and removal is not possible). So is Google Adsense capable to deliver aliases to solve these sort of problems!

In a nutshell : 
(1) The javascript Google Adsense User Id "google_ad_client ID" is public searchable!
(2) How to get ALIASES to maintain privacy between different websites ?

In a smaller nutshell : 
Using Google Adsense, How to maintain between websites privacy ?

Thank you for any information,
Taca
p.s. : I haven't seen any serious Google platform I could have ask my question from, was redirected to a very old thread! It's a bit like if Google is not interested in direct interaction with its users because they are so many of them and because they have enough anyway! Hopefully I am wrong!

Comment: Load the adsense code a-sync via your own code? Or hide your code, via something like `base64_decode(BASE64STRING)`. Easy to implement. Security through obscurity

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't mask your adsense ID.

Why don't you sign up with a different email address?

Comment: Because it's not only a new eMail I would need, but a different phone number, a different bank account and probably a different name to have things secured, because they ask all that and specify many times that they don't want the same users with many different accounts! So it would be clever from their side to provide aliases so privacy between sites is possible!